# Is $\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} f(x-m)f(x-n) \in L^2(a,b)$ if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $0<a<b< \infty,$ put $A= \{x\in \mathbb R: a<|x|<b\}.$
Fix $n\in \mathbb Z.$ Define
 $$ F_n(x)=\sum_{m\in \mathbb Z} f(x-n-m)f(x-m)$$
We note that $F_n$ is a periodic function with period 1.  And hence we cannot expect $F_n$ belongs to $L^2(\mathbb R).$

> But can we expect  $F_n\in L^2(A)$?

I'm also curios to know what happens of summation over $n$? Specifically, define 
$$G(x)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} F_n(x).$$

> Can we expect    $G\in L^2(A)$?

Comment: What exactly is the role of $A$ in the definition of $F_n$?

Comment: @ClementC.Thanks.  Since $f\in L^2,$ it cannot be periodic.

Comment: My earlier (now deleted) comment was mistaken, I read $f$ for $F_n$. But read the new one -- what is the role of $A$ in the definition? Does it just appear in your question?

Comment: @ClementC.: Just the measure of $A$ is finite.

Comment: @ClementC. Since we cannot expect $F_n\in L^2(B)$ if $B$ is of infinite measure, thus I'm taking $A$ such that its measure is finite. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not even sure $F_n$ is necessarily defined. For instance, assume wlog that $1\in A$ (otherwise, translate the whole construction) and let $f$ be a square integrable non-negative function such that $f(n) = 1$ for every integer $n$ (such a function exists). Then $F_n(1) = \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}} 1 = \infty.$

Comment: @ClementC.: Thanks. But showing  square integrable the function  should be defined just all most every where? Please let me know if I have missed something. Thanks.